# How to read original data based on isolation levels

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isolation-level

My test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Personel](
    [PersonelID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Personel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonelID] ASC
)
)
```

My Test Data:

```
insert into Personel
values (1, 'Jack')
, (2, 'John')
, (3, 'Kevin')
```

Connection A:

```
begin tran
update Personel
set Name = 'Michael'
where PersonelID = 1
```

Connection B:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL ????

SELECT Name 
FROM Personel WITH (????)
where PersonelID = 1
```

Connection A starts a transaction and is trying to update data, but transaction is still going on. Connection B tries to read the data that is being updated.

Is there a way (an Isolation Level or a hint or combination of these two) to see the original data (Jack, not Michael)  before the transaction is committed or rolled back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the old version of the data in the SNAPSHOT isolation level.

This requires that the database has snapshot isolation enabled before you start:

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
```

Then in connection B

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

select * from Personel
```

There are some performance considerations with snapshot isolation, because it duplicates the rows read into tempdb.

[Documentation reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

SNAPSHOT (aka. row versioning).

Under snapshot isolation the connection B will see the data as-it-was when ti started the transaction in connection B (even if you did not start an explicit transaction, there is an implicit transaction started by the SELECT statement). See [Understanding Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Read operations performed by a snapshot transaction retrieve the last
>   version of each row that had been committed at the time the snapshot
>   transaction started.

SNAPSHOT support must be explictly enabled in teh database:

```
ALTER DATABASE <DatabaseName> SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
```